# <uses permission> in android studio is not working / application is not asking for permission

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make an app which starts by asking permission and accesses the hotspot of any device and any android version with which the very first problem which is bothering me is that why  is not working, i have tried it on two devices and both of the attempts were unsuccessful.Please can anyone help me out to point my mistake. I checked similar questions related to it and have tried correcting it too but still not working..
here is the xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.akshay.turnonhotspot2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: you have to ask for permission at runtime..after getting to know how permissions are requested at runtime you can get rid of boilerplate permission code try this library https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Answer (score 2):

It is changed since Android API 23.
You also have to ask permissions at Runtime.
[Check this document](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are asked when when you need user personal data such as contacts, storage(photo, video, file) and etc..

You don't need to ask permission for *android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE*

Comment: Thank you for this information, but when I am using wifimanagerand WIFI_SERVICE class the android studio is asking for permissions in the manifest.xml otherwise its showing error